# dmenu auto execute command if only one option is left

Tags: linux, dmenu

is there a way of having dmenu automatically exectue a given command, if there is only one option left?

What I mean is this:
Say I have a set of options:

1. Execute A
2. Execute B
3. Execute C

etc. When I type "1", dmenu automatically filters the options and I only have the option

1. Execute A

left showing. But, I still have to press enter for it to start.

Is there a way, where if will automatically start? Like, for example, the file browser "ranger", when using the find (f) command. When it is down to one option, matching the typed String, it will automatically move you to that sub directory, without having to press enter.

Cheers all.

Comment: dmenu doesn't execute programs. It reads a list from stdin, presents the items in a graphical menu and outputs user's chosen item or typed in text to stdout. dmenu_run script uses dmenu to execute programs. As for your question, you could modify the source code for dmenu to just output the item to stdout if the list consists of a single item.

Comment: Alternative is to modify the dmenu_run script to only call dmenu when there are multiple lines to pass to it.

Comment: @Vilinkameni
Thanks for the answer. I can not yet confirm, if what you said works, as it will take me a little bit to understand and then try it all, (I am still rather new to all this). However, it did already give me quite a few pointers I can use to research further. If I do not forget, I will come back and add, if the suggestion works, in case someone else has the same question and stumbles upon this post in the future. Cheers and have a nice day.